# Lose access to part of my database when I switch to a different server location

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest

Context: I am using mongoDB to store my data on my first API, it's made in node.js. I'm currently working on creating a login system. When I post the account to my API I set the _id value to the email address so to access it I can just do api.com/logins/email. Whenever I do that I get this in return
`{"_id":"email","password":"password","__v":0}`

However when I switch the server location (from my server to my laptop for dev testing) I can no longer access the logins by _id. I can still access the entire collection, but when I attempt to call specifically by the _id I get `Cannot GET /logins/email` This also happens if after the fact I reopen the API server on my personal server

In order to fix this I have to delete all the collections in that area and re add one from the app. Once I do this everything works again however when my app goes live I would want to have this fixed because otherwise everyone would need to remake their accounts when I do work on the API

With this being my first API I'm kind of at a loss for what's happening and why it is, any help would be appreciated

Relevant code from sign in page (yes I am aware that base64 isn't encrypting I just haven't change it yet)

```
    const login = async () =>{



     encrypted = (await encrypt())

 
    console.log(email.toUpperCase())
    var mail = email.toUpperCase()

    var test = await fetchSingleData(url,mail)
    console.log(test)
    if (test==null){

      console.log("Invalid email")

      return
    }

    console.log(test.password == encrypted)

    if (encrypted == test.password){
      console.log("I'm in")
        setEmail("")
        setPassword("")
        navigation.navigate("Sheet")

    }
    else console.log("Invalid Password")

  
  }

const encrypt = async () =>{


  var enc = Base64.encode(password)
  console.log(enc)

  return enc


}
```

Mongoose connection code

````
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
require('dotenv/config')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const MONGOBD_URL = process.env.DB_CONNECTION
var https = require("https")
var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path")


app.use(bodyParser.json())


//Import routes
const postsRoute = require('./routes/posts')
const loginRoute = require("./routes/logins")

app.use('/posts', postsRoute)
app.use('/logins', loginRoute)



//ROUTES
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{

res.send("We are on home")


})


//LISTENER
app.listen(19010)

//Connect to DB
mongoose.connect(MONGOBD_URL,{useNewUrlParser: 
true},()=>{console.log("connected to DB")})

module.exports = app;```
````

Routing

```
const express = require('express')

const router = express.Router();
const Login = require("../Models/Login")

//GET ALL ACCOUNTS
router.get('/',async (req,res)=>{
    console.log("req")
    try{
        const logins = await Login.find()
        res.json(logins)
    }catch(err)
    {
        res.json({message: err})
}
    


})
// CREATES ACCOUNT
router.post('/', async (req,res) => {

    const login = new Login({

        _id: req.body._id,
        password: req.body.password

    })



//SPECIFIC ACCOUNT
router.get('/:postID', async (req,res) =>{
    try{
    const login = await Login.findById(req.params.postID)
     res.json(login)
    }
    catch(err){res.json({message:err})}
 })

   const savedLogin = await login.save()
   try{
    res.json(savedLogin)
   }catch(err){
       res.json({message: err})
   }
})


//DELETE ACCOUNT
router.delete('/:postID', async (req,res) => {

  
  try{
    const remove = await Post.remove({_id:req.params.postID})
     res.json(remove)
    }
    catch(err){res.json({message:err})}
})



module.exports = router
```

Data example in database

[image: Data example in database]

Comment: Hi, can you add sample data of your relevant collection, then please add the code that connects your ```NodeJS``` app to your database. Also please add the implementation code for your logging-in functionality.

Comment: Could you clarify on what you mean by sample data? Because I believe that's already there in the first paragraph. I will go ahead and add the other stuff though

Comment: Cool, add in the an example of the data in your database...

Comment: That should be everything you asked for, lmk if I misunderstood anything/you need more info

Comment: Is your DB connection address ```localhost``` by some chance?, from what I'm gathering in your question. It looks like a statement bugs out before configuring your routes so that is why you get ```Cannot GET /logins/email```. So I'm suspecting your DB connection

Comment: Also in your route, are using ```app.post('...', ...)```? That would then explain the ```Cannot GET /logins/email``` because it is configured for ```post``` maybe...

Comment: So it has routes set up that I forgot to include, thays my bad. And yes it happens on local host, but it also happens when it's running on my dedicated server through a domain and a port number

Comment: K please add that also, but in the mean time, make sure the connection URL to your database is to the same server, if you are using ```localhost``` as your database address your API will try connecting to a local database which has different data to the one on you main server...A case a ill referencing

Comment: I'm a little confused by your wording. When I switch the api code from my server to my laptop and re run it, I change the url in the react native app for the online domain to local host with a port. The database url never changes in the API

Comment: k, does this guy ```process.env.DB_CONNECTION``` have ```localhost``` in it?

Comment: No it doesn't. Like I said it connects to my mongodb cluster and it doesn't change

Answer (score 0):

okay so let us get to this...I'm not too sure what the cause of this issue is, but let us go through your code and try to isolate it. So we will begin by neatening things up a little.

starting with your login code:

```
const login = async () => {
  encrypted = (await encrypt())

  var mail = email.toUpperCase()
  var test = await fetchSingleData(URL, mail)
  // [TIP]: this is sufficient to achieve the same logic.
  if (!test) {
    return
  }

  if (encrypted == test.password) {
    setEmail("")
    setPassword("")
    navigation.navigate("Sheet")
  }
  else
    console.log("Invalid Password")
}
//...
const encrypt = async () => {
  return Base64.encode(password)
}
```

Okay let check out your route configuration.

```
// [TIP]: import everything first
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

// [TIP]: const on everything that wont change
const https = require("https")
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path")

require('dotenv/config')
const MONGOBD_URL = process.env.DB_CONNECTION

const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json())

//Connect to DB
// [FIX]: Connect to the database first before referencing it in your routes
// [NOTE]: Express is a static server and cannot change after configuring
//         the routes that you have.
mongoose.connect(MONGOBD_URL,
  { useNewUrlParser: true },
  () => console.log("connected to DB"))

//Import routes
const postsRoute = require('./routes/posts')
const loginRoute = require("./routes/logins")

// I do not know what goes on here
app.use('/posts', postsRoute)
// or here, but suspect your issue lies here.
app.use('/logins', loginRoute)

//ROUTES
app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
  res.send("We are on home")
});


//LISTENER
app.listen(19010, () => console.log('server listening on port 19010'));

module.exports = app;
```

Im still not sure what the problem could be with this code, my suspicion is still with your database connection.

Comment: So you're code still presents the same issue, and for context I posted the routing page for login, the posts route was just for testing when I was first setting it up

Answer (score 0):

So in the end the issue was my brackets. They were set up in a way that so that the singular get was only created when I did a POST